# Rollback a certain amount of transactions during deveopment?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, testing, transactions

Are there any tools around that monitor db transactions transparently and allow for batch rollback? Something similar to what DBunit offers but not in the context of a unit test but for a slightly longer period of time (say for a test that lasts 5-10 minutes, done in the UI and not in a automated test)

Like: a developer integrates a new feature and tests it interactively. 10 minutes, the data is messed up and he wants to go back to a safe state of the database.

Backups / snapshots are not suitable here as the database is pretty large and going back to a backup / snapshot is time consuming. So something that is more lightweight would be preferred.

Btw, Windows SQL Server 2008 Standard is used, so we cannot use snapshots at all. Technology stack for the application is Java / JPA / Hibernate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything available to achieve what you describe. You have to manage your own transactions on your connection to the database.

You could start a transaction at the beginning of your tests and then roll it back at the end but that has the side effect of locking the tables preventing others from using the DB.

You might want to look at using a SQLite database, loaded with test data, which you use then "throw away". It's fast and great for testing.

Comment: The problem is that we really need to work on that one huge database as we cannot extract test data from it easily due to RI constraints. I also thought about wrapping a test into one surrounding tx but as you mentioned this will lock out other developers.

Comment: I'm suggesting you have a complete copy of your database but implemented in SQLite. Are you testing the handling of large amounts of data, or the table structures? I realise it can be a big task to generate the test database but it would at least be reusable.

Comment: It's more about the data integrity. Chances are that some data gets corrupted or overwritten with bogus data so we want to ensure that we can go back to a safe state in the database. And we want this to be flexible and quick - so I thought that there are some tools already that would handle this.

Comment: An alternative might be to use audit tables, if you are only a couple of tables where the data will become corrupt. That way you can "roll back" to a point in time by updating the original table from the audit table.